# Terminal auto-completion does not work

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, auto-completion

The auto-completion in the terminal doesn't work that means that nothing happens.
Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS

a) `echo $SHELL` is `/bin/bash`

b) I reinstalled the bash completion package with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash completion
```

c) The file .bashrc contains the following:

```
#enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable

#this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile

#sources /etc/bash.bashrc).

if ! shopt -oq posix; then

  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then

    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion

  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then

    . /etc/bash_completion

  fi

fi
```

d) The file `/etc/bash.bashrc` is the same like above.

e) `echo $0` is `bash`

f) `shopt -s progcomp` nothing changed

h) The file `he file /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` exists.

i) the outut of `compgen -c apt-` is:

> apt-config
> apt-cdrom
> apt-sortpkgs
> apt-cache apt-add-repository
> apt-get
> apt-key
> apt-ftparchive
> apt-mark
> apt-extracttemplates

j) `ind -q complete`

> complete can be invoked via "\C-i", "\e\e".

It is a new installation.

Comment: Hello. I am not seeing a version of Ubuntu mentioned in the question. Always include the version as this may affect the answer.

Comment: `echo $0` would be more definitive than `echo $SHELL`

Comment: `echo $0` is bash

Comment: Does the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` exist - and does it have any content?

Comment: You're missing a dash - the correct install command should be: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion `

Comment: Make sure there *is* something to autocomplete before deciding it does not work. In your question, add at least a few examples that do not work for you but should work in a default Ubuntu install so one can reproduce and confirm the issue is your system, not you.

Comment: `shopt -s progcomp` thne try again please.

Comment: The file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` exists. What does not work is `apt-    `. I tried `shopt -s progcomp` nothing changed.

Comment: So does `compgen -c apt-` output anything?

Comment: Here is the output of `compgen -c apt-`:                                                                      `apt-config
apt-cdrom
apt-sortpkgs
apt-cache
apt-add-repository
apt-get
apt-key
apt-ftparchive
apt-mark
apt-extracttemplates
apt-config
apt-cdrom
apt-sortpkgs
apt-cache
apt-add-repository
apt-get
apt-key
apt-ftparchive
apt-mark
apt-extracttemplates`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the diagnostic information from your comments, and explain **exactly** how it's not working

Comment: Based on the `compgen -c` output, command completion is working. If the TAB key isn't working to *initiate* completion, then that suggests a problem with your readline keybindings (have you messed with the readline configuration files /etc/inputrc or ~/.inputrc)? Please add the output of `bind -q complete` to your question.

Comment: Everything so far looks like it should be working - are you hitting TAB twice or just once?

Comment: I cant explain it too. I hit it once.

Comment: I tried to install the version 21.10, but it is the same.

Comment: Unless you have \C-i bound to menu-complete (which is not the default) then AFAIK you need to hit TAB twice when there is more than one possible completion.

Comment: ok i taped twice but its the same.

Answer (score 0):

i think auto complete its set by default on linux. you have to press `tab` after starting some command to do it. if auto complete does not work you have to check your command in `command line`